# Stop getting user relationships by default (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, axios, laravel-7

Whenever i call

```
$user = \App\User::find(Auth::user()->id);
return response()->json($user);
```

it returns the user along with the relationships but I didn't ask for it.

```
{
 
 "id":51,
 "name":"Admin",
 "username":"administrator",
 "avatar":"1592477660_FB_IMG_15890226824693948.jpg",
 "cover":"1592477660_Goku-Dragon-Ball-Z-1710x900.jpg",
 "gender":"male",
 "posts":[
       {
        "id":19, 
        "body": "this is the body"
       },
       {
        "id":20, 
        "body": "this is the second body"
       },
       {
        "id":21, 
        "body": "this is the third body"
       },
  ]
}
```

I don't want to eager load all posts belonging to the user I just want the user but this is the default behavior. What if the user has more than 1000 posts? this would get really messy.

Post.php

```
class Post
{   
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'body',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User
{   
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'body',
    ];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this should not happen. If you do not call `->with('..')` or `->load('..')` anywhere and you do not have a property `protected $with = ['..']` defined in the User model, something is wrong and you should not try to solve this with a workaround.

Comment: If this is the whole code then something is wrong with the User class. It acts like there is $with property in it although it is not. Have you tried these commands?:  php artisan config:clear and compser dump-autoload? Could you also provide whole Controller code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `makeHidden()` method to hide attributes and relations you don't need.

```
$user = \App\User::find(Auth::user()->id)->makeHidden('posts');
return response()->json($user);
```

The makeHidden() hides the attribute temporarily. If you want to permanently hide attributes in all queries, you'd have to add it to your model like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['posts'];
}
```

If you want to eager load the posts, you should use the `makeVisible()` method in your query:

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->with('post')
        ->makeVisible('posts')->get()
```

Comment: Does this mean all my queries have to look like this?

Comment: The makeHidden() attribute hides it temporarily, I have modified my answer to include making it permanent so you wouldn't have to hide it in all queries

Comment: thanks it worked but what if i want to eager load the user's posts on purpose. Will it still be hidden?

Comment: $user = \App\User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('posts')->get();

The posts are hidden

Comment: Add the makeVisible() method to your query `$user = \App\User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('posts')->makeVisible('posts')->get()`;

Comment: Also, you should check the method name for your post in the User model. I have noticed the method name is `post()` but you are using `with('posts')` instead of `with('post')`

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: So your query should be exactly like this `$user = \App\User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('post')->makeVisible('posts')->get();`

I will modify the answer to include this

Comment: This would work but it's merely a hack and would make my codes look ugly if i have to pass ->makeVisible() and ->makeHidden() all the time.
It's not acceptable but it works

Answer (score 0):

you can use [without](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method witch is specialized for this:

```
$user = \App\User::without('posts')->find(Auth::user()->id);
return response()->json($user);
```